# C# registration form after admin first login

Tags: ado.net

I have a login form in C# where the administrator will login with "admin" as username and "admin" as password.  I want to modify it so that the second and subsequent logins will not accept the default administrator credentials.

Here is my current code:

```
    private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=login1;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from user2 where username = '"+textBox1.Text+"' and password = '"+textBox2.Text+"'", cn);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate usernameand password");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("username and password is incorrect", "Please try again");
        }
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        }

    private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

How can I implement the revised behavior I described?

Comment: Post some code that you've written.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you probably need some another table column to store information about first login, for example boolean value which corresponds whether the user already was an administrator or not.